# How to delete file which contain space in key from S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have some file on S3 bucket containing space in key. All the other files which don't have space in between key are deleted properly but with space its throwing error **"Error Message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch;..."**

Here is actual code:

```
private void deleteFileAndFolder(String bucketName, String folderName, AmazonS3 client) {
        List<S3ObjectSummary> fileList = client.listObjects(bucketName, folderName).getObjectSummaries();
        for (S3ObjectSummary file : fileList) {            
            client.deleteObject(bucketName, file.getKey());
        }
        client.deleteObject(bucketName, folderName);
    }
```

Tried to remove space from key.

```
    String key=StringUtils.replace(file.getKey(), " ", "+");   
    LOGGER.debug("BucketName:{},fileKey: {}",bucketName,key);
    client.deleteObject(bucketName, key);
```

but its seems not working properly.

Comment: What happens if you replace space with %20 instead of plus sign?

Comment: Same error "Error Message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch;..."

Comment: A 403 error from AWS related to your signature typically means your credentials are invalid or you do not have the permissions to delete.

Comment: @Compass HTTP 403 Forbidden does cover AccessDenied but in this case the error code is SignatureDoesNotMatch, so it's not related to permissions.

Comment: @Compass I am able to see all file list from bucket in fileList object so I guess it not about credential

Comment: This works fine with the latest v1 aws-java-sdk (1.11.563). No need to encode the spaces. I can create, list, get, and delete an object with literal space characters in its key.